# inner join on UScensus2010 package

Tags: r, inner-join

I have a data frame below that I created from the USCensus2010 package. Previously it was a numerical vector. The problem is the first column does not have its own variable name. If you look below, the data frame only sees one column. I want to use only the values in the first column to inner join another data frame to, but I do not know how to separate the first column from the second, so that the data frame has 2 variables and not one. Can someone help me out. Thank you for your patience as I am a beginner.

```
NewYork <- as.data.frame(demographics(dem = "P0010001","NY",level="tract"))

> head(NewYork)
        P0010001
36099951000     2154
36099950700     3929
36099950500     3917
36099950100     2452
36099950900     3861
36099950800     6173

> str(NewYork)
'data.frame':   4919 obs. of  1 variable:
$ P0010001: num  2154 3929 3917 2452 3861 ...
>
```

Comment: try: as.data.frame(rownames(NewYork))

Comment: Thank you. This is how it looks :
 NewYorkNames <- as.data.frame(rownames(NewYork))
 head(NewYorkNames)
 rownames(NewYork)
1       36099951000
2       36099950700
3       36099950500
4       36099950100
5       36099950900
6       36099950800
but I would like it to look like this:
New York       P0010001     
36099951000    2154
36099950700    3929

Comment: I don't have the data on hand. See if this helps: data.frame("NewYork" = rownames(NewYork), P0010001 = NewYork$P0010001)